# Galaxy Nexus restarts non-stop before completely booting

Tags: reboot, factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I'm aware of the suddenly restarts of the `Galaxy Nexus`, but in my case it restarts before managing to boot completely and it does that in a non-stop loop. It happened while my phone was on a stand by mode and now I can't do much, so it is basically useless.

Is there anything I can do about it. Is it possible to reset it somehow? I tried to remove the battery, charge it and all that kind of stuff that I could do, but no luck so far.

I bought it through Amazon.com and the model is [Samsung I9250 Galaxy Nexus 16GB (Unlocked)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005ZEF01A), but I'm in Europe so warranty is something that would take sometime I guess.

**Update:** I also tried to follow [these instructions](https://plus.google.com/107538503004482952974/posts/K8wozE8zhzq) but my computer cannot find the device. I'm stack in the `ODIN MODE, Do Not Turn Off Target` if I do the trick with the volume down button, otherwise it just restarts without completing the initial colorful effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would unlock the bootloader, and flash a new image...

You can find all the information you need on this page:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1392310

Hope you found my answer helpful :)

Comment: I would like to have the original Google's ROM.. I haven't go through the article yet.. but is it going to work without me being able to start the phone?

Comment: You should be able to push the new image to the phone through fastboot mode.. If you can come in fastboot mode, its is almost always possible to save it...

Comment: And google image is possible to find here:
http://code.google.com/android/nexus/images.html
It is google which have uploaded them :)

Comment: Are you Danish? If so i can probably better help you on Androidforum DK, where i'm a mod. I have also translated the Toolkit into danish if you need it, right here:

Comment: Sorry, here is the link :)
http://androidforum.dk/showthread.php?8690-Opdateret-Samsung-Galaxy-Nexus-Toolkit-1-klik-s-unlock-root-og-recovery-metode&p=49162#post49162

Comment: And i have a wuistion on my own, if someone maybe could answer it for me? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19368/how-do-i-use-a-external-microphone-on-my-galaxy-nexus-to-video-recording

Comment: Thanks dev0 for all the info.. I'll deal with that soon most likely following that post, but not over the weekend :) I'm in denmark but I don't speak danish and we'll find a solution it would be nice to have here a canonical answer as well!

Comment: Okay great :)
I wil try and look in this thread every day, so if you need anymore help, i will properly be here :)
Have a nice weekend

Comment: It looks like I'm on brick mode.. :( I also tried to do that (https://plus.google.com/107538503004482952974/posts/K8wozE8zhzq).. but my computer refuses to recognize the device.. I'm stack on the _odin mode. do not turn off target_ If I'm going to do the trick with the volume down key, otherwise it just restarts before completing the colorful effect during boot :(

Comment: Have you installed the drivers on your pc? The tool need the drivers, before it can recognize your device...

Comment: No luck.. I tried to follow the stuff with the ToolKit but didn't manage to restart/unlock or root or whatever... somehow windows recognized the device but I couldn't do much regarding that.. the ToolKit wouldn't find it.. :( I'll give you the bounty.. but I still have a brick :) Any idea if I could just go to my company's retail shop and ask them if they could do something about it even though I didn't buy it from denmark?

Comment: You can get it fixed in denmark, by Telecare, but it will cost money...
Are you sure you have installed the USB driver correctly on the computer? Via PDANet the¨ software

Comment: Via the PDANet software?

Answer (score 2):

Something might have overwritten some files needed during boot.

Go into recovery and do a factory reset. Yes this is the same thing as factory reset in the Settings but the difference is that you dont need to boot the OS to do it.

There is usually a button combination you press to get into recovery. Google it for your device. Once you factory reset, try again.

WARNING: Factory Reset will wipe all user data on your device. Sorry.

If you reboot and everything is working, then it was your user data.
If you reboot and the same thing happens, then that means your actual system is corrupted. This means like dev0 said, you have to flash a new image or send it in for warranty.

Just because you flash a new image, doesnt mean you cant get a stock rom image. Chances are, someone on XDA has a stock ROM image that is exactly the same system as when you first got it. People have these images in the event someone wants to go from a custom ROM or version of Android to stock.

So yeah, follow dev0's links and advice. Rooting and unlocking the bootloader might void your warranty so find out before you do it though!

Comment: Can't do much.. the phone is not recognized by the computer :( read my last comment from dev0's answer

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I just googled this. It doesn't help but helps me :) Now I wont do a default factory setting on my Galaxy Nexus. [Clicky.](http://androidspin.com/2011/12/17/got-a-verizon-galaxy-nexus-dont-do-a-factory-rest-or-unlock-the-bootloader-just-yet/)

You can try [this page](http://androidadvices.com/hard-reset-samsung-galaxy-mobile/) if it has the same functionality as Samsung Galaxy S

Comment: Nope.. no help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `Cyanogen` ROM? If so, try other roms such as **MIUI**.
I had this problem exactly as you on my `Nexus S` with **Cyanogen** and after migrating to MIUI all the **reboots**, **booting animation loops**, **shuting downs on standby** and etc. gone.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with my Galaxy Note after installing a lot of apps and filling up the 32GB SD card. I haven't managed to figure out what exactly the problem is, maybe it is totally different (since there are different Android versions).

Anyway, I'd start by removing the SD card, but Nexus doesn't have a removable card slot...

If you're using stock ROM, check out if there's an updated version of your ROM available. Search xda-developers forum, it may have a thread that lists all stock ROMs available for your device.

Some of the stock ROMs are "wipe" and others are "non-wipe". You can try flashing non-wipe stock ROMs on your device and see if it fixes the issue. (you don't need root or custom recovery for this, if Nexus works the same way as my Note). But anyway, I'd recommend making a nandroid backup before doing so.

If you have USB debugging enabled already, you might be able to get the system logs from a PC, if the phone gets to the point during the boot that can connect to adb. But if you don't have the USB debugging enabled, since you can't boot and go to settings, this won't work. If you could get logs of the system, it may give you a clue of what is causing the phone to restart.

If it didn't fix the issue, I think your only option is to boot into recovery (hold power + home + volume for 10 seconds or so) and do a factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem with my GN and followed the instructions in http://support.sprint.com/support/tutorial/Perform_a_hardware_factory_reset_Galaxy_Nexus/37165-396
Please note that all of your data will be deleted.

Comment: You've followed those instructions and still have the problem? Or did those instructions solve it? In the latter case: [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies.