# Guitar recording on Android?

Tags: toshiba-ac100, audio-recording

I've tried to plug my electric guitar into Toshiba Thrive tablet and record some music using the default Sound Recorder app.

I found that the tablet recorded sounds as if the guitar is not attached to the tablet, there was a lot of noise and the guitar sound was not clear.

When I plug my guitar to the sound card of the PC the sound produced is similar to what I hear when I plug the guitar to a real guitar amplifier; the sound is **"clean"**. I expected the same when plugging into the tablet.

Is there a method to achieve the same clean sound on my Android tablet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The info I'm finding [suggests](http://www.thriveforums.org/forum/toshiba-thrive-audio/1077-external-microphone-through-headphone-jack.html#post9438) that you need a 4-ring TRRS connector to use a mic, and that the bundled Sound Recorder app will ignore this regardless and just use the internal mic, so you'll need a different recording app.

Comment: This is correct... You need another app, which can record from an external microphone/input... Look in this thread where you can find a link to one of those apps...

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19368/how-do-i-use-a-external-microphone-with-my-galaxy-nexus