# Is it possible to isolate audio input/output devices?

Tags: bluetooth, audio, headphone-jack, bluetooth-audio

Is it possible to make the 3.5mm audio jack port of an Android device into a purely audio INPUT device (something like a mic)? I would like to see if I can receive audio input via the jack and push out the said input to a bluetooth headset.

If this is not possible, why?

If it is, how would I go about implementing it?

Comment: This seems like a development question, which are off topic here. This SE website focuses on the Android operating system as a whole, not developing for it. Your question might get more attention, and better answers at [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @John - I'm not looking for code. Simply wondering if this is possible.

Comment: the `how would I go about implementing it?` sounds a bit like a development question. That said this question has already been asked: [How do I use an external microphone with my Galaxy Nexus?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19368/how-do-i-use-an-external-microphone-with-my-galaxy-nexus)

Comment: @John - I don't want an actual mic. If I connect it to the audio jack of my laptop, I want the laptop's output.

Comment: Oh alright, so you want to use your device as a mic over bluetooth?

Comment: This question seems perfectly on-topic to me.

Comment: @AlEverett This question is really confusing to me, it might be the wording but I thought he was trying to attach a mic to his Android device using the audio output jack, and then use the output of the mic over bluetooth to his computer. But now in a comment, he said he wants to connect his device to his laptop using the audio output? I am very confused by this question.

Comment: @John - Please give the question another read. I said "audio INPUT device" "something like a mic" not a mic but something like it.